# Keep variables on a server in memory, avoiding a database, for a flex app

Tags: sql-server, database, actionscript-3, apache-flex, cgi

Im building a game with a lot of players and I want to find a way to store player positions and serve them out again quickly, i dont need this information to be written to disk.

All the examples I can find use a script that runs once to retrieve some information from a database.

What is the best way to do this in flash builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider checking out Adobe Cirrus for P2P communication.
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

It appears this tutorial shows how to setup the client and server for a multi-player game using C# and AS3 as well:

http://playerio.com/documentation/tutorials/building-flash-multiplayer-games-tutorial/

Comment: Yeah Ive had a look at cirrus and I think Im going to use it for some things. I am going to need a tiny it of server-side logic.

Comment: The second Article is very helpful, especially the server stuff. It is using compiled c# code, I was hoping there would be a solution that could be done in python as I know it much better.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with Python.  Not really a C# guy either but I know Java well enough to be dangerous, and I understand partial classes, so I get the langauge syntax well enough that I could probably port to Java, unfortunately my Python knowledge is limited to hello world so I can't help you there but I imagine you could port all the same concepts and implement them in a python way.  Best of luck.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your help, Ive done a bit more research and I think I can do the stuff hes doing in c# in python. If I do a search for "socket server python" I get heaps of info. Its funny when you know the right terminology it makes things so much easier.

Comment: Yah google is amazing when you know what you're looking for that's gotta be like 90% of stack overflow questions, just don't know what you're looking for, it's why I love this site.  If you come up with a solution post it as an answer to your question, if you can.